# Getting a delimiter issue while executing the script

Tags: bash, shell-script, ed

I am creating a `test.sh` file and i am running it as `./test.sh`:

```
string="hello"
ed << EOF
e any_file
1i
${string}
EOF
```

can anybody help me what it does?

I am getting some delimiter issue. Can anybody tell me how to do this?

Comment: What does “some delimiter issue” mean? Copy-paste any error message. Also post a complete script that reproduces the problem (again, copy-paste).

Answer (score 2):

your script is incomplete, as it misses the terminating `EOF` literal.

i try to explain the script:

the first line simply assigns "hello" to the variable `string`.

```
 string="hello"
```

the 2nd line starts the `ed` command, and feeds it (via `stdin`) the following lines until it encounters the `EOF` literal (`<< foo` means: the following lines until `foo` are redirected to the `stdin`)

```
 ed << EOF
```

the following lines are `ed` commands.

open a file called *any_file* (`e any_file`), and insert `1i` the string `${string}` (this will be expanded to "hello").

but since you are missing the terminating `EOF` literal, the stdin-redirection throws an error.